# Unable to call Fortran sub-routine in R (R crashes)

Tags: r, crash, fortran

I have following example code `test.f90,` which I am trying to compile using [Lahay Fortran](http://www.lahey.com/) (x32-bit) at my Windows 10 (x64-bit) machine.

```
! Computes the square of a number

Subroutine sr1(a,b)
implicit none

#ifdef COMPILER_GF
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sr1
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'sr1' :: sr1
#endif

#ifdef COMPILER_IF
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL ::sr1 
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE, ALIAS : 'sr1' :: sr1
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: a,b
#endif

#ifdef COMPILER_LF
    dll_export sr1
#endif

integer a,b
b = a*a
End Subroutine sr1
```

At Lahay Fortran command prompt, the following line does everything and create `test.DLL`.

```
lf95 test.f90 -win -dll -lfe- "-Cpp" -lfe "DCOMPILER_LF" -ml msvb
```

Now, I am trying to read this `.DLL` in `R (x32-bit)` using:

```
dyn.load("path_to_file/test.dll")
is.loaded("sr1")
#Returns TRUE
```

The `DLL` loads into `R` fine. But, when I am trying to call the subroutine, `R` crashes here:

```
.Fortran("sr1", a=as.integer(2), b=as.integer(4))
# R crashes here
```

Does anyone have any idea why or what could be the workaround to fix the issue?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: But, variables a,b are defined as Integers already in the sample code. So why it should be tested as as.double ()?

Comment: If you are using the regular downloadable R, it did not use Lahey Fortran, and likely expects a different calling convention.  You should read the R Installation and Administration manual to see if there's any advice on what you need to do, but it doesn't mention Lahey.

Comment: @user2554330: Yes, I am using usual Windows dowloadable R. Does it make any difference if I compile from a source?

Comment: Sorry about the noise, I was too much in a hurry to read your code carefully.

Comment: As far as I know, nobody has tried to compile R in Lahey Fortran, so building from source might be an awful lot of work.  But if you did that successfully, it could make `.Fortran` work better for you.